# Show that for a Noetherian ring R, the R-module R$^{n}$ is Noetherian

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I'm allowed to use this:

An R-module M is Noetherian when a submodule N is Noetherian and their quotient M/N is Noetherian.

In my particular problem, M = R$^{n}$ and N = R.  I believe I will have to show that for any i, R$^{i}$/R is Noetherian.  I think I will have to use induction on n to prove my result.  Does this sound right?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Actually, any finitely generated $R$-module is noetherian if $R$ is.

Comment: This does not make sense as written. $R$ can be found as a submodule of $R^n$ in many ways. Which do you mean?

Comment: Well, it depends on what $R$ means. There are isomorphic copies of $R$ in there such that the quotient isn't free. Take $H=\{(2n, 2n)\}\mid n\in \Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ for example, which has nonzero torsion elements. Of course it's fine if the copy is just the first coordinate, which might be what you mean

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that sounds right. Note that $R^n/R = R^{n-1}$, hence $R^n$ is Notherian if $R^{n-1}$ is (as $R$ is Notherian). Your result follows by induction.

---

Addendum: We embed $R \to R^n$ via $r \mapsto (r,0,\ldots, 0)$.